# Problems with html RTE Editor in TYPO3 7.6 with Safari Browser

Tags: safari, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, rte

I'm using TYPO3 7.6.32 where I have a problem with my editor in the backend with the Safari browser. In all other browsers this does not appear.
Does anyone know this problem and know how to fix it?

This is the screenshot of the backend in the Safari browser:
[image]

Best Regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the release of Chrome 73 the Rich Text Editor (RTE) of TYPO3 is broken. Safari and Chrome both use webkit as basis so I assume, the problem is the same.

Since TYPO3 7.6 is End of Life (EOL) since [end of November 2018](https://typo3.org/article/this-is-the-end-for-typo3-v7-lts), there is no official patch. You're strongly advised to upgrade your TYPO3 installation to at least TYPO3 9.5.

If this is not possible, you can try to [manually patch](https://blog.reelworx.at/detail/how-to-fix-rte-in-typo3-7-lts-for-chrome-73/) your TYPO3 installation or to use Firefox instead.

Answer (score 2):

TYPO3 7.6.32 is unsupported since december 2018. The problem you describe has most likely already been fixed in TYPO3 7.6 [ELTS](https://typo3.com/landingpages/all-about-typo3-v76-elts)

The old TYPO3 RTE (htmlarea) has been removed from the TYPO3 core since TYPO3 version 8.7. There is a public repository available with code of the old RTE, where a [possible solution](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/rtehtmlarea/issues/43) for your problem may be available.

Anyway, since your TYPO3 version contains several known security issues, I strongly suggest that you either update to a community supported version of TYPO3 or to a TYPO3 version with Extended Long Term Support.