# Why is the editor not working correcly in TYPO3 version 7.6?

Tags: typo3, rte

I have updated an old site from 6.2 to 7.6 but now the RTE editor is not working correctly for existing content and for new content.
The RTE editor is shown, but the text area just shows `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><head></head><body></body></html>`, which cannot be edited or deleted.
If I press the "<>" button I can see and edit the html code.

I have tried deactivating the rtehtmlarea extension and re-actvating it, but this did not help. I have also tried creating a new admin user, but this did not help.

I have just seen that the rtehtmlarea version 8.7.3 is marked as obsolete. Which extension should I use together with TYPO 7.6? There seems to be so many!

The status report says there are conflicting extensions installed for the htmlArea RTE, but does not say which extensions. In the list I can only see rtehtmlarea. How can I find out which other one is causing the problem?

Comment: please share a list of the installed and active extensions; could also this be a javascript error? Did you try to delete the browser's cache?

Comment: I do not know how to get a list of the extensions and there are too many to type them by hand.I have no idea if this is a javascript error, no messages are shown. I have tried it with 3 different browsers.

Comment: Look for the /typo3conf/PackageStates.php file; it contains the active extensions only.
I see that you have updated your question; on version 8.7.x and above RTEHtmlarea has been replaced with the extension CKEditor, which is included in TYPO3.
You should use your browser inspector to look for javascript errors.

Comment: I am using TYPO3 version 7.6, the rtehtmlarea exstension is at version 8.7.3. The CKEditor is in the state of experimental, and when I try to install it I get a warning saying it requires TYPO3 versions 6.1.0 to 6.2.99, so mine is to high. Are you sure this is the correct replacement for rtehtmlarea?

Comment: I am really messed up now! Although I said cancel to the CKEditor it seems it has been added to the list and now I cannot see the extensions anymore. I just get an error message "The extension ckeditor has invalid version constraints in depends section".

Comment: I have been imprecise; the official name of the extension shipped with TYPO3 8.7 is "rte_ckeditor" and is included with TYPO3 (/typo3/sysext/rte_ckeditor);  Sorry I ignored that there was a third-party "CKeditor" obsolete extension

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227118/discussion-between-riccardo-de-contardi-and-amanning).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with html RTE Editor in TYPO3 7.6 with Safari Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64772167/problems-with-html-rte-editor-in-typo3-7-6-with-safari-browser)

Comment: I think that the problem here is that this user has 1) disabled the check for compatible extensions; 2) Installed the rtehtmlarea version from TER 3) installed also an old CKEditor extension from TER, too

Comment: Sorry to have been away so long, some family matters got in the way. I have tried to apply the patch, but that didn't help. Edge and Chrome display it incorrectly, but Firefox works OK.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the combination of a webkit based browser and the outdated TYPO3 version 7.6. Please see my [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64775299/3946047).

Comment: The patch did not solve the problem with the Edge and Chrome browsers.